# What does 'excluding the systematics' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A business user asked me if I can run the report for her 'excluding the systematics'.  Does that mean without going through the formality and procedure and etc?

Comment: What kind of report is it?  What do you usually do to run the report?

Comment: just a regular business report, i don't think the type of report plays an important role here.

Comment: Why didn't you ask her what she meant?  I'm an educated native speaker, and I don't understand every phrase people say to me--often because they make it up on the spot!

Comment: @DeepYellow: Yup, I should have done so in the first place.  But I wanted to make sure it's not some terms that everyone but me understands.  It turned out that it was related to the report specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notion that the type of report doesn't matter probably is wrong; and most probably you need to ask the user to show you what report elements she wishes to have excluded.

If the report covers stock trading results, you might need to exclude "indices that track the performance of an algorithmic trading strategy", as noted in wikipedia [systematic indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_Indices) article.  For other reports, the meaning may be analogous, but as there does not appear to be a unique, widespread, or well-known referent for "systematics", I doubt that anybody other than the user involved can answer your question.

It's quite unlikely that she meant "formality and procedure and etc".  (By the way, "etc." means "and so forth".)

Comment: You are absolutely right about the report type.  It turned out that the users wanted to exclude the 'systematic stuffs' and that 'stuffs' are all the trades generated by the system automatically.  Problem solved. It's amazing you have so much insight without a lot of the context of the situation.